# Is there any good method to initialize 2-D array in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I want to initialize a Identity Matrix (ones on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere) with a 2-D array.
I try to implement this with `vector`. The code is like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix;
matrix.resize(n);
for(auto &i: matrix)
    i.resize(n);

// initialize...
```

This is far more complex than just with ordinary array with just `int matrix[n][n]`. I don't do this because I want to return this 2-D matrix. So the function is like this :

```
matrix_type
func(int n)
{
  //intialize the matrix
  ...
}
```

Because the array in C++11 is like this:

```
array<Elem,N> arr;
```

I have no idea how to get the N at runtime. Then I decide to use the vector.

So is there is a better way to handle this?(without using traditional array)

---

Thanks for the answer. The question can be solved by use

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(n));
```

And , another question. If I am a stupid guy and I just want to use the  interface, that is , I want the return type to be 
`array<int,n>`. So is there any method to get the N at runtime and return it?

Comment: What is the reason you cannot use the 2D array approach? All of these methods would work for what you need, which one would you prefer to implement?

Comment: The ordinary `int matrix[n][n]` doesn't work with `n` unknown at compile time as well.

Comment: Oh this is just for curiosity. Since STL has defined a new <array> interface. So I am wondering if there is a good method to solve this problem by using just STL.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko  Yes that't true. Thanks for pointing out. Then things get more complicated~~

Comment: Note that a vector of vectors is an inefficient representation of a matrix. A flat vector of rows stored consequetively is better.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, that's true. But the code to access a  matrix is much more natural with a 2-D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the construction/initialization of the matrix to:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(n, std::vector<int>(n));
```

The above line will initialize all the elements of the matrix to 0. You can set the values of the diagonal elements to 1 using a `for` loop.

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
   matrix[i][i] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes! I have forgotten this ! That's a good answer! Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a 2D array of `std::vector<T>` as follows:

```
 template<typename T>
 using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

 template<typename T>
 Matrix<T> make2DArray(int N, int M){
     return Matrix<T>(N, std::vector<T>(M));
 }
```

Calling it like:

```
 auto my2Darr = make2DArray<int>(20, 30);
```

Comment: There are too much of std::vector<std::vector<T>> in this solution, consider making a typedef 
`typedef Matrix std::vector<std::vector<float>>;` or if template T is really needed `template<typename T> using Matrix<T> = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;`

Comment: @V.Kravchenko, Good catch. updated. Thanks ..